# equal spacing between uiimageview using size class

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios8, xcode6, size-classes

I'm trying to add four or (more in future) uiimageview in ipad application landscape mode. I want equal spacing between each uiimageview. I used wRegular hRegular format to build the application and used few constraints, but when i try to run the application in simulator i'm getting different result for different iPad devices. How can i achieve having equal spaces between uiimageview irrespective to size of the screen ? Below is the screen shots.

iPad2:[image]

iPad Air : [image]

iPad Retina : [image]

Resizable iPad : [image]

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout is a system that lets you lay out your app’s user interface by creating a mathematical description of the relationships between the elements. You define these relationships in terms of constraints either on individual elements, or between sets of elements. Using Auto Layout, you can create a dynamic and versatile interface that responds appropriately to changes in screen size, device orientation, and localization.

Try this link to learn about Size classes and Auto layout.
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/